# Why Experience Manager need to be installed for the DXA?

Tags: dxa, experience-manager

DXA requires installation of the following SDL Web Software components :

1. Content Manager
2. Experience Manager
3. Content Data Store
4. Content Service
5. Deployer Service
6. Context Service
7. Discovery Service

But why does DXA require XPM to be installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experience Manager doesn’t have to be installed, but DXA has built-in support for XPM. This obviously won’t work if you don’t install XPM.

But, again, it is perfectly possible to use DXA without XPM.

Comment: oh yes i missed it . In SDL DXA docs it is mentioned DXA requires installation of this components. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Is there a reason to _not_ install XPM?

Comment: nope alvin just it crossed my mind so posted question on that..